# Breakpoint jumps to another function/class in VB.NET (VS2008)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug my code (VB.NET) and I place my breakpoint on a line of code.

I attach to my TEST server and when the debug symbols load, the breakpoint line disappears from where I put it, and relocated it to a totally other line, in another function in another class.

I tried rebuilding the solution, rebuilding a clean solution.  I even closed VS2008, and even rebooted my machine.

Has anyone come across this before and what can I do to get this to bebug where I put my breakpoints?

Many thanks in advance for any help.
Sean

Answer (score 2):

Have you deployed the PDB file to the server and is it up-to-date?

Answer (score 0):

Try using F12 on your function calls and see where they are coming from and setting break points there, then steping through the functions to get where you need to be at.